# Bootstrap 3 navbar and media queries issues

Tags: media-queries, twitter-bootstrap-3, navbar

I have 2 questions.

1- Why is the drop downs on this menu not working on my ipad:  [www.dyhas.com/jonas](http://www.dyhas.com/jonas)

It works fine on a desktop and works fine in my iphone (after is snaps closed with the toggle button)  but when I click on one of the drop downs in my ipad nothing happens.  Furthermore, it is spilling over into two lines instead of creating a toggle button?

2- I am using media queries in my LESS file.  These do not seem to be working correctly though as when I am in tablet landscape it does not apply them.  Where am I going wrong with the queries?  It seems to work for something but not others.. for example I want the navbar menu font to go to 12 when on a tablet both landscape and portrait but it is only applying it on portrait.

```
    @screen-xsmall:              480px;
    @screen-phone:               @screen-xsmall;


    @screen-small:               768px;
    @screen-tablet:              @screen-small;


    @screen-medium:              992px;
    @screen-desktop:             @screen-medium;


    @screen-large:               1200px;
    @screen-large-desktop:       @screen-large;


    // large desktop
    @media (min-width:@screen-large-desktop) and (max-width: 2500px) {
         h1, .h1 { font-size: @font-size-h1; } // ~62px
        h2, .h2 { font-size: @font-size-h2; } // ~52px
        h3, .h3 { font-size: @font-size-h3; } // ~40px
        h4, .h4 { font-size: @font-size-h4; } // ~29px
        h5, .h5 { font-size: @font-size-h5; }   // ~28px 
        h6, .h6 { font-size: @font-size-h6; } // ~24px     
    }
    // medium desktop
    @media (min-width:@screen-tablet) and (max-width: @screen-desktop) {
        h1, .h1 { font-size: @font-size-h1; } // ~62px
        h2, .h2 { font-size: @font-size-h2; } // ~52px
        h3, .h3 { font-size: @font-size-h3; } // ~40px
        h4, .h4 { font-size: @font-size-h4; } // ~29px
        h5, .h5 { font-size: @font-size-h5; }   // ~28px 
        h6, .h6 { font-size: @font-size-h6; } // ~24px 

        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
            font-size:12px;
        }
            .bannerButton a {
                width: 100px;
                padding:5px;
                margin:5px;
                font-size:12px;
        }
    }
    // smalls screens tablet& landscape phones
    // If screen is > than phone and < max tablet
    @media(min-width:@screen-phone) and (max-width: @screen-tablet) {
       h1, .h1 {font-size:@font-size-base + 12px;}
       h2, .h2 {font-size:@font-size-base + 9px;}
       h3, .h3 {font-size:@font-size-base + 6px;}
       h4, .h4, h5, .h5 {font-size:@font-size-base + 2px;} 
       .login-form {
           margin-left:8px;
           margin-right:8px;
       }
       .btn {
           margin-bottom:8px;
       }
       a > .configText {
            display:none;
       }
        .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
            font-size:12px;
        }
        .bannerButton a {
                width: 100px;
                padding:5px;
                margin:5px;
                font-size:12px;
        }

    }
    // xtra small screens. phones


       @media(max-width:@screen-phone) {
           body, p, blockquote {font-size:@font-size-base - 3px;}
           h1, .h1 {font-size:@font-size-base + 7px;}
           h2, .h2 {font-size:@font-size-base + 4px;}
           h3, .h3 {font-size:@font-size-base + 2px;}
           h4, .h4, h5, .h5 {font-size:@font-size-base;}   

            .navbar-inverse .navbar-nav>li>a {
                font-size:12px;
            }
                .bannerButton a {
                    width: 100px;
                    padding:5px;
                    margin:5px;
                    font-size:12px;
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

I think i figured it out, I had a large gap in my media query setup and I figured out how to override the snap point for the tablet navbar.